# On dynamic nature of memory, C++ example

Tags: c++, memory

Consider the following snippet

```
int x[] = {1,2,3};
cout << *x << endl;      // 1
cout << *(x+1) << endl;  // 2
cout << *(x-10) << endl; // Different number each time i run the program
```

Why is it that last `cout` consistently display a different number each time i run the **compiled** program? It is understood that result is unpredictable and is undefined, but i would imagine it should be consistent. Why does it change?

Comment: This is impossible to answer, IMO.

Comment: It depends on what OS you are running - some operating systems have a security feature which makes stack contents unpredictable.

Comment: @PaulR Not contents I hope. The location could be though.

Comment: @Captain: well, contents too, indirectly, since some of the data on the stack will be other addresses within the stack.

Comment: You're reading off the top of the stack (x86 stack grows down in memory space), which has presumably never grown beyond `main`'s activation record. In other words, your program has never written to that address. Even if ASLR isn't in effect, the result will be determined by what ever happened to live here previously.

Comment: Because **undefined behavior** means that anything can happen, and this is in the realm of possible behaviors. Why does sometimes a program crash and sometimes not ? (for the "same" thing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory block you are trying to access is not legally owned by your array and the program. That portion of memory would be owned by some other process going on. so every time it holds different value. It is also possible that you get the same answer some other time.

Answer (score 3):

Why should it be consistent? Its a pretty much random value of your computers memory.  `x` doesn't always point to the same location and the contents of `*(x-10)` changes as well.

Answer (score 2):

as you mentioned, it is undefined behavior…

one explanation: you are reading arbitrary/random memory. who knows what it was used for before you read it?

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior.  You also might have [Address space layout randomization (ASLR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Answer (score 0):

If you understand that the result is unpredictable and undefined, then why do you also think it must be consistent? There are no guarantees for anything when reading outside of your memory. It might as well crashed the program.